# Add an alternate stylesheet in IE11 with script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css

Consider this [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/rupebocoju/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Case</title>
  <!-- red -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css;base64,aHRtbCB7YmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjpyZWR9" />
  <!-- blue -->
  <link title="a" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css;base64,aHRtbCB7YmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjpibHVlfQ==" />
  <!-- green -->
  <link title="b" rel="deferred" type="text/css" href="data:text/css;base64,aHRtbCB7YmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjpncmVlbn0=" />
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var elem = document.querySelector("link[rel=deferred]");
      var parent = elem.parentNode;
      parent.removeChild(elem);
      elem.rel = "alternate stylesheet";
      parent.appendChild(elem);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Run the example and in Firefox and Chrome, the background of the page will be red. Run it in IE11, and the background will be green.

Can anyone shed any light on why IE11 is styling the page to the added stylesheet even though it is marked as an alternate only?

UPDATE:

Further investigation shows that this only happens when re-using the link element. Creating a new link element is fine, so it seems that in IE, the "alternate" flag on the element is not being updated when the `rel` attribute changes.

Answer (score 1):

`rel="deferred"` isn't a [valid link type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) so IE will ignore it and load the base 64 reference. 
By setting it to `rel="alternate stylesheet"`, the browser still requests the resource on page load but will not render it.

It seems you're trying to both defer loading of the CSS resource and then (once it does load) prevent the browser from rendering it? Worth reading [Debunking Responsive CSS Performance Myths](https://www.igvita.com/2012/06/14/debunking-responsive-css-performance-myths/) by Ilya Grigorik to see how these techniques don't always work as you'd hope them to.

Comment: Thanks for the link. An interesting if dubious read (it suggests using a `disabled` content attribute that isn't valid on link elements). In my case the performance gain obtained is real and noticeable, definitely not a myth.